# Stop openoffice from launching browser, disable hyperlinks

Tags: windows, openoffice

I use openoffice to read xls... I do not want openoffice connect to internet, EVER

if xls contains hyperlink, openoffice launches my default browser

how do i stop this?

I tried manual proxy options , but that doesn't work when openoffice launches browser

it is acceptable but not optimal solution to stop every winxp application from starting browser

Thanks